# why i am not getting output in this code?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title> javascript </title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript switch</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let x = prompt('enter no');

switch (x) {

           case 0:
              text = "off";
              break;
           case 1:
              text = "On";
              break;
           default:
              text = "No value found";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in the above code i want user to enter the input and then i want to display output but every time i try to do this the the only defaut=lt output comes output , why?

Comment: Because `prompt` returns a string, not a number. Try `case "0"`

Comment: Because `"1" !== 1` debug `console.log(x, typeof x, x === 0, x ===1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Number() to convert to a numerical value

```
let x = Number(prompt('enter no'));
```